# Погоны - погонять?

Tags: этимология

Если я правильно понимаю, слово ***погоны*** изначально не имело единственного числа и обозначало плечевой крепеж для эполет *(матерчатый клапан с проволочным каркасом - он и сейчас используется, только немного другой  конструкции)*. Это понятно. Но не объясняет связь со словами *погонять, погонный (метр)* и проч. Я объяснений не нашел.

Есть версии?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Версии есть, а насчёт их доказанности - как сказать.

Ясно, что слово из заимствованных, но давно освоенных. Заимствовано, скорее всего, из польского (во времена улан, в европейских армиях уланы были с 16 века), туда, видимо, попало из греческого.

Вот перевод с греческого текста о Святославе: в  греческом оригинале значится pogon epsilomenos, что на самом деле означает "редкая борода". Погон - борода.

А наплечный знак  различия у военных в виде широкой нашивной или накладной полосы по виду напоминает бороду, особенно когда появились эполеты(фр.).В одно время погон – "нашивка на мундире, на которой крепился эполет".

В России погоны появились  во времена  Петра Первого,он был предназначен для удержания лямки-патронницы, традиционно носимой на плече обыкновенных солдат. Немного позже погон обзавелся парой и стал предназначаться для крепления ранца.

Когда слово попало в русский язык, оно оказалось созвучным др.-р.слову «гонар», что дословно означает гордость или честь. С давних времен считалось, что порабощение детей, женщин, стариков - некая форма лишения чести, или гонара, освобождение своих взятых в плен сородичей - высшее предназначение воинов, участвующих в битве за правое дело, или, как ее еще можно назвать погоне. Вот и получилось: кто участвует в погоне, в битве - тот носит погон.
Так что  погоны в той форме, в которой они представляются сегодня, вернули слову первоначальное значение, олицетворяют военную гордость и честь мундира, который вояка получает за несение отличной службы во благо своей страны. Становится понятным выражение «отдать честь», сопряженное с преклонением перед заслугами старшего по званию. В то же время публично сорвать погоны означает лишить военнослужащего его чести, опозорить, подвергнуть гонению и осуждению сослуживцев.

Comment: Людмила, версий пока не вижу. Начнем от печки. Погон, по вашему мнению, связано с "погонять" или это случайное созвучие?

Comment: Нет, погон-не от "погонять"и вообще не от корня "гон", это омоним, появившийся как заимствование, его Пётр 1 привёз в готовом виде как лямку на плече  в виде бороды(погона). А вот воспринялось оно на Руси как слово, созвучное "погоне", ведь "гон" в др.-р. яз.означало "погоня и участок земли, расстояние", в и.-е. тоже было слово "гонос" загонная охота, в др.-греч. "убийство", т.е. ассоциации с военной профессией были, оно прижилось. А тут ещё близкое "гонар"-честь. Вот и стал погон знаком отличия.

Comment: *погон-не от "погонять"и вообще не от корня "гон", это омоним* - похоже... Забыл уже про этот вопрос, но вот напомнили, а ничего более толкового не сказали.

Answer (score 0):

Слово возникло в результате смещения значения, первоначально – "приспособление (полоса, нашивка и т. д.) для закрепления чего-либо", **произведенного от глагола погонять**. Изначально погон – "нашивка на мундире, на которой крепился эполет".

Выделенное, как отвлекающее, можно не принимать во внимание, заменив на "произведенное от слова "гон". [Гон | onlinedics.ru](http://www.onlinedics.ru/slovar/bes/d/gon.html)

Одно из значений этого слова - град, градация - (лат. gradatio - постепенное повышение - от gradus - ступень, степень), последовательность, постепенность в расположении чего-либо,последовательно расположенные этапы, ступени при переходе от одного к другому. [Градация | onlinedics.ru](http://www.onlinedics.ru/slovar/bes/g/gradatsija.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Из словаря Черных:**

В Петровское время **погон – это наплечный ремень для ружья**, например: 7 тыс. ружья солдатского, из которого 3 тысячи с погонами. Старшее значение – **тесьма**:  булочник носит лоток на погоне.

У Даля: "**Погон - тесьма на платье у военных людей** по плечу от воротника до рукавного шва, служит у рядовых для укрепления перевязи". **Погоны в качестве знаков различия появились только  с 1732 года.**

Итак, погон изначально  - это отрезок тесьмы, и **Даль относит это слово к группе "гнать, погонять"**, где гон - мера длины (сравнить: погонный метр).

**Примечание**

Черных рассматривает вариант погон от оgон (шнур, жгут, польск.), но считает его неприемлемым ни с семантической точки зрения, ни по фонетике (как объяснить начальное "п"), ни по хронологическим соображениям.

Comment: Даля я читал. Его этимология всегда сомнительна, но он здесь её и не раскрывает вовсе.  Черных тоже ничего внятного не сказал. *Внимание вопрос* Что есть этимологического общего у "тесьмы" и "погона"/"гнать"? Как могло значение "тесьма" распространиться на гнать/погон?!

Comment: Гон (мера длины)  - длина борозды, распаханной в один прием. Из говоров (костром.): гон - длинная и узкая полоса пашни. Тесьма, ремень  - тоже узкая и длинная полоса материи.

Comment: Хорошо. Понял. В такую этимологию не верю. Случайное сближение - в лучше случае."Гон" - как мера длины вопросов не вызывает. Но при чем тут узкое и длинное? Т.е. тут для обоснования родственности  надо, чтобы гон - перешло на меру длинны (реально, как сказал, но только расстояния, дороги), оттуда на понятие "погонный" [метр] (уже сомнительно), "погонный" - на тесьму  (с чего бы?), и уже с тесьмы - на погон (ну это тоже готов допустить)...  Сама по себе цепочка длинновата, да еще  два слабых звена из четырех... Не, не верю.

Answer (score 0):

У охотников ружейный ремень до сих пор называется погон. Нашивка на плече под погон (ружейный ремень) сначала названия не имела, а позже переняла название ружейного ремня. Т.е. название сместилось. 
А вот почему ружейный ремень - погон? На мой взгляд происхождение этого слова связано со словосочетанием "погонный метр" - т.е. единица длины чего-то длинного, протяженного, есть такое слово "прогонистый" - длинный и тонкий. Погон, следовательно, тоже длинный и тонкий, каким и является ружейный ремень.

Answer (score 0):

Позволю себе оставить мнение. Слово "погоны" сходно со словом "поганый" и латинским paganus и толкование должно быть одно для каждого из них.

1. **Погоны**. Будем отталкиваться от слова "**погонный**" в смысле погонный метр, погонная сажень; смотрим у Вл. Даля на "**поганивать**" - у него идёт отсылка туда  от слов "погон" и "погонный". **Погонный** - это отрезанный кусок чего-то, служащий мерой равной длины, причём подвижный, *переставляемый*. В таком случае **погоны - это отрезы** или ***полосы*** ткани **равной длины** на плечах военнослужащих, погоны могут отстёгиваться, они подвижны, они могут меняться на другие и они обозначают про**движение** по службе; там же корень "**гон**", который означает **движение**; а звёздочки и нашивки-это принадлежность этих погонов:

> " Погон, прут или **полоса**, по которой *ходит что-либо*, рельс, и ||
> самый простор, разбег, пространство для движенья взад и вперед: скоба
> или **побегало**...".

2. **Поганый**.

а) поганый - языческий, также **лат. paganus - язычник**. Смотрим словарь Даля ["поганивать"](https://gufo.me/dict/dal/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C). То есть "поганый" в смысле "гонимый":

> "За ворами в погон побежали".

б) поганый - *ругательное* плохой, например "Чудо-Юдо поганое". Такое же значение, "тот, кого надо погнать":

> " Погонять, погнать сев. погонить, понуждать к бегу, к скорому
> ходу...",

- в смысле "заставить убежать", "прогнать".

в) поганый в смысле "плохой", "негодный", например "*гриб поганка*", "*испоганить одежду*" - испачкать, привести в негодность, "*птица поганка*" - негодная к еде. Здесь смысл у слова "поганый" - "оторви и выбрось", то есть "погнать", "прогнать". У Даля там же смотрим:

> "**Погонки** м. мн. остатки в кубе от перегона чего, гуща, подонки,
> осадок при перегонке, выгонке.",

- то есть **негодные остатки**.
  Таким образом одно слово "поганивать" объясняет происхождение целого куста слов: погоны, поганый и латинского paganus(язычник). Сюда же фамилия скрипача Паганини или Paganini - Языческий, гонимого церковью.

P. S. Спасибо автору behemothus за то, что поднял эту тему, я искал объяснение слову paganus и наткнулся на ваше обсуждение.

Answer (score -1):

Посмотрите, как выглядят монгольские пайдзе! Знаки, дающие право пользования казенными дорогами и лошадьми, т. н. "погонные". "Пайдзе" — от *пойдем*, *пойду*.

Comment: Не понял, при чем тут "монгольские" погонные и каким образом слово может быть связано с русским. Где вывообще это слово нашли? Оно совершенно не похоже на монгольское.

Comment: А, "пайцза". Ну так оно вообще не от русского слова, никак не может быть связано ни с погонами, ни с погонными. Что за ерунда вообще...

Answer (score -1):

Гербовые наплечники-погоны ailettes, носившиеся рыцарями до появления настоящих металлических наплечников, в связи с тем что они, как и тогдашние щиты, были сделаны из дерева и кожи, носились в основном на турнирах и парадах, в отличие от настоящих погон служили лишь для ношения гербов.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%8B%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C

Погон - производное от польского "Pogon", что означает герб "Погоня" - самый распространенный герб на наплечном щитке времен ВКЛ (с конца XIV века).
В самом гербе у конного рыцаря, изначально, наплечный щиток с изображением ягеллонского креста, который, со временем, вырос до полноценного щита.

В русский язык слово "погон", не изменяясь, пришло из польского.

Comment: Ээээ... Это все очень интересно, но совершенно не аргументировано. Да и к заданному вопросу имеет весьма далекое отношение... Если я правильно понял, вы возводите "погон" к корню "гон" (пусть и через польский), против чего возражают авторитетные источники (Фасмер, Черных и др.) В такой ситуации хотелось бы видеть источник вашего Откровения.

Comment: (+) pogon по-польски и означает "погоня", "преследование" , ничего более. С гербом "погоня" стало ассоциироваться равзе что в Белоруссии (и не в те времена, когда она была частью ВКЛ). "Герб" на польском - herb.

Comment: В той же Википедии приводится ссылка на источник, в котором объясняется, что процитированная в ответе версия происхождения погон является широко распространённым заблуждением.